# QGIS: Clipping a Vector layer line on a another line?

Tags: qgis, clip

Currently I have some Profile lines that have been clipped based on polygon layers which created some temporary lines, but right now I am trying to clip the total profile with a temporary merged line of the clip. So that I only have the parts I do not have that could be clipped. **Here is the situation the red line is the merged clip layer and the black line is the layer under it.**

[image]

I want to clip the **blackline based on the red line but since the clip alogrithm only takes polygons I am kinD of confused how to do it**. Clipping based on Polygon is not an option here.

Comment: So, you want to remove the red part from the black line?

Comment: That is the gist of it yes. But ofcourse as seperate temporary layer.

Comment: Then... why dont you use the polygon, which is visible in your screenshot?

Comment: For one I tried it before but I have only clip the blackline based on the merged polygon...I only get the same red line back. So not exacly an option.

Comment: You could use `difference`?

Comment: Thank you that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In ArcMap, you can clip the total profile with a temporary merged line of the clip. [image]

Here, in the first image you can see the total line which is not clipped.
Second image, red lines indicate your temporary merged line of the clip.
Third image shows the yellow lines which are clipped results of black line with red lines.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I was looking in the QGIS, but got the sollution.

Comment: Can't you do the same procedure in QGIS?